# How to trigger a 404 page if the URL doesn't match any controller or function

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

You need to add a 404 error page. This page should be called if the URL does not match any controller or function that is in the project.
please help me I don't know how to do this

**App.php**

```
<?php
class App {

    protected $controller = 'Home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if(file_exists('app/controllers/' . ucfirst($url[0] ?? null)  . '.php')) {
            $this->controller = ucfirst($url[0]);
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once 'app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new $this->controller;
        if(isset($url[1])) {
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl() {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return explode('/', filter_var(
                rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'),
                FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

please help me I don't know how to do this

Comment: Is this your own custom framework or an open source one? My guess is that `view()` takes an array that is either the QS or at least contains it.

Comment: Indeed, an array is received in view(). Thank you, I understand everything works.